# Sorting an NSArray that contains int with particular int

Tags: objective-c, sorting, nsarray

I have some data like this :

1, 5, 2, 9, 7, 6, 3, 8, 0, 4

but I actually want this:

5, 6, 7, 8, 9

only start to 5 .

and I use this:

```
NSArray *ary = @[ @"1", @"5", @"2", @"9", @"7", @"6", @"3", @"8", @"0", @"4" ];
NSArray *myArray = [ary sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:
                    @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"doubleValue" ascending:YES]]];
```

Comment: FYI - your array doesn't contain numbers. It contains strings.

Answer (score 1):

```
NSString *numberExpr =@"^[5-9]";
NSArray *ary = @[ @"1", @"5", @"2", @"9", @"7", @"6", @"3", @"8", @"0", @"4" ];

NSArray *myArray= [ary filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self  MATCHES %@",numberExpr]];
```

Comment: then what u exactly want to achieve

Comment: I'm not the one who asked the question.  I simply pointed out to future readers that your solution has a weakness.

Comment: agree but there may be alphabets or digit after each "5 to 9". If so then this is solution. If only digit then  NSString *numberExpr =@"^[5-9][0-9]*"; And if any alphabets then NSString *numberExpr =@"^[5-9][0-9A-Za-z]*";

Comment: answer is better meet to question's requirement and also person satisfied with the answer who have asked question. So can't modify given answer

Comment: If you notice, the question includes sample code which sorts on `doubleValue`.  This indicates that he 1) knows he has strings, and 2) wants them treated as numbers for purposes of sorting.  This means your answer does not satisfy the requirements as stated.

Comment: There's the old joke "If you have a problem, use regular expressions. Now you have a big problem". Using regular expressions to handle numbers is so totally, totally wrong. If the requirement changes to "only numbers from 5 to 25" you are totally f***ed.

Comment: @gnasher729 Close, it's *"Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems."*. Attributed to [Jamie Zawinski](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Jamie_Zawinski)

Answer (score 0):

This solution treats the contents as numeric, as suggested by the question's sample code.

```
double startingValue = 5;

NSArray *ary = @[ @"1", @"5", @"2", @"9", @"7", @"6", @"3", @"8", @"0", @"4" ];

NSArray *myArray= [ary filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self.doubleValue >= %@", @(startingValue)]];

myArray = [myArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:
                @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"doubleValue" ascending:YES]]];
```